# Partial view in ASP.NET always outside of <tr>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, razor-pages

I am trying to render my partial view inside table row (which is inside thead tag) but I`m always have the view rendered outside of the row . Here is the code:

```
<tr id="lineTimes">
                <th> <partial name="LineTimesRow" model="Model.LineTimes" /></th>                             
</tr>
```

Quick inspection of DOM shows following:
[image]

What even more strange is that if I put this partial view inside of tbody tag then it renders just fine:

```
 <tbody id="lineTimes">              
            <partial name="LineTimesRow" model="Model.LineTimes" />
 </tbody>
```

[image]

I`m trying to investigate this for like 5 hours - without any luck. Can someone point me to the right direction? Any help will be appreciated.
Here is the whole code snippet:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover text-center arrow-nav table-line-times">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Artikel
                </th>
                <th>
                    &nbsp;
                </th>
                <th>THT</th>
                <th>lotsize</th>
                <th title="Incr lotsize">incr</th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ViewHeader, "WeekplanningDateHeader")
            </tr>
            @*<tr id="lineTimes">
                <th> <partial name="LineTimesRow" model="Model.LineTimes" />  </th>                             
            </tr>*@
        </thead>
        <tbody id="lineTimes">              
            <partial name="LineTimesRow" model="Model.LineTimes" />
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Days)
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
```

EDIT:

Fixed it - the issue was in the partial itself and my lack of understanding on how table nesting works. My partial were combined of table rows (tr) elements. And because I am trying to inject it into another table row (tr element) it is just ignored because tr cannot be inside another tr just "as is" - (nested tr needs to be wrapped in table). Mystery solved!

Comment: You are missing the closing `/>`

Comment: Mistyped it here in the question, have everything closed in the code (still having that issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it - the issue was in the partial itself and my lack of understanding on how table nesting works. My partial were combined of table rows (tr) elements. And because I am trying to inject it into another table row (tr element) it is just ignored because tr cannot be inside another tr just "as is" - (nested tr needs to be wrapped in table). Mystery solved!